# XPATH for checkbox where id, type and name is same in Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, checkbox

please look the Below code:

what will be the XPath for `id= idConfirmedCheckbox`?

```
<td class="tdCenter">
<input id="idConfirmedCheckbox" type="checkbox" onclick="return idConfirmedClicked(this);" name="idConfirmedCheckbox"/>
<input id="Customer_Person_Identifications_Identification_0_Confirmed" type="hidden" value="N" name="Customer_Person_Identifications_Identification_0_Confirmed"/>
<input id="Customer_Person_Identifications_Identification_0_NotConfirmedDisabled" type="hidden" value="" name="Customer_Person_Identifications_Identification_0_NotConfirmedDisabled"/>
</td>
<td class="tdCenter">
<input id="idConfirmedCheckbox" type="checkbox" onclick="return idConfirmedClicked(this);" name="idConfirmedCheckbox"/>
<input id="Customer_Person_Identifications_Identification_1_Confirmed" type="hidden" value="N" name="Customer_Person_Identifications_Identification_1_Confirmed"/>
<input id="Customer_Person_Identifications_Identification_1_NotConfirmedDisabled" type="hidden" value="" name="Customer_Person_Identifications_Identification_1_NotConfirmedDisabled"/>
</td>
```

Comment: Updated. I think you want a single element which have same id. I belive you forget to mention it. updated my answer. Let me know if facing any issue

Comment: What exactly you want to get using xpath? Also could you provide code/screenshot which is above in hierarchy to td element(<td class="tdCenter">) you provided

Comment: if there is id and name why you need xpath?

Answer (score 0):

Try below Xpath:

```
//input[@id='idConfirmedCheckbox']
```

OR

```
//input[@id='idConfirmedCheckbox' and @type='checkbox']
```

OR

```
(//input[@id='idConfirmedCheckbox' and @type='checkbox'])[1]
```

Change the array to 1 to 2 or 3 as per required

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id='idConfirmedCheckbox' and @type='checkbox'][2]"}

//input[@id='idConfirmedCheckbox' and @type='checkbox'][1]" has successfully checked but while checking second one This above error is coming.

Comment: you are doing it wrong I have given different xpath which .. the xpath I mentioned is (//input[@id='idConfirmedCheckbox' and @type='checkbox'])[1] while you are trying //input[@id='idConfirmedCheckb‌​ox' and @type='checkbox'][2]

Comment: you are missing the closing brackets